Triangle doesn't show up in Vulkan
I've built multiple renderers with Vulkan, but I have no idea what's wrong here. I'm using dynamic rendering.
I've double checked everything from pipeline creation to draw calls in RenderDoc. I can see the mesh and shaders in RenderDoc and the pipeline should work. I also don't get any validation errors.
void Render()
    Renderer::DrawData drawData;
    if (m_Renderer.BeginFrame(drawData)) {
            VkViewport viewport {
                .x = 0.0f,
            .y = 0.0f,
            .width = (float)m_Renderer.m_GpuSwapchainExtent.width,
            .height = (float)m_Renderer.m_GpuSwapchainExtent.height,
            .minDepth = 0.0f,
            .maxDepth = 1.0f,
        };
        VkRect2D scissor {
            .offset = { 0, 0 },
            .extent = { 
                            m_Renderer.m_GpuSwapchainExtent.width,
                            m_Renderer.m_GpuSwapchainExtent.height 
                        },
            };
        vkCmdSetViewport(drawData.commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
        vkCmdSetScissor(drawData.commandBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);
        VkRenderingAttachmentInfo colorAttachment{
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_ATTACHMENT_INFO,
            .pNext = nullptr,
            .imageView = drawData.swapchainImageView,
            .imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
            .resolveMode = VK_RESOLVE_MODE_NONE,
            .resolveImageView = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
            .loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
            .storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
            .clearValue = { .color { .float32 { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } } },
        };
        VkRenderingInfo renderingInfo {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_INFO,
            .pNext = nullptr,
            .flags = 0,
            .renderArea = scissor,
            .layerCount = 1,
            .viewMask = 0,
            .colorAttachmentCount = 1,
            .pColorAttachments = &colorAttachment,
            .pDepthAttachment = nullptr,
        };
        vkCmdBeginRendering(drawData.commandBuffer, &renderingInfo);
        CameraData1* cameras[1] = { &m_GameCamera };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            for (GraphicsPipeline& pipeline : m_GraphicsPipelines) {
                vkCmdBindPipeline(drawData.commandBuffer,
                                VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline.m_GpuPipeline);
                for (Entity* entity : pipeline.m_Entites) {
                    VkDescriptorSet* pDescriptorSets = nullptr;
                    VkBuffer* pVertexBuffer = nullptr;
                    VkBuffer* pIndexBuffer = nullptr;
                    uint32_t meshCount = 0;
                    MeshData* meshes = nullptr;
                    entity->RenderUpdate(pipeline, *cameras[i],
pipeline.m_DescriptorSetCount, &pDescriptorSets, meshCount, &meshes);
                    if (pDescriptorSets) {
                                        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(drawData.commandBuffer, 
                                    VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline.m_GpuPipelineLayout, 0, pipeline.m_DescriptorSetCount, pDescriptorSets, 0, nullptr);
                    }
                    if (meshCount && !meshes) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    for (uint32_t j = 0; j < meshCount; j++) {
                            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(drawData.commandBuffer, 0, meshes[j].vertexBufferCount, meshes[j].vertexBuffers, meshes[j].vertexBufferOffsets);
                                    vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(drawData.commandBuffer, meshes[j].indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
                                                vkCmdDrawIndexed(drawData.commandBuffer, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        vkCmdEndRendering(drawData.commandBuffer);
        m_Renderer.EndFrame();
    }
}

I've also turned of face culling and depth goes from 0 to 1 everywhere.
